# Singular fit error caused by random factor

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, singular-matrix

I'm trying to fit a generalised mixed model for some embryo data and I am getting the error for singular fit.  my model is

```
m1=glmer(segregation ~ total + carrier.gender + (1 | couple/cycle), data=data1, family=binomial)
```

I can see the variance for both random factors is 0. If I take out the random factors of couple and cycle I do not get this error but for the sake of my experiment I can not exclude these factors.  Some of the cycles only include 1 embryo while others have many.  Is this the reason for the singular fit?  If so is it OK to ignore this message or do I need to adjust my experiment somehow?

```
summary(m1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
  (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: 
segregation ~ total + carrier.gender + (1 | couple/cycle)
   Data: data1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1138.7   1162.3   -564.3   1128.7      830 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5164 -1.0245  0.7200  0.8689  1.2760 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 cycle:couple (Intercept) 0        0       
 couple       (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 835, groups:  cycle:couple, 242; couple, 141

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         1.0982377  0.2591267   4.238 2.25e-05 ***
total              -0.0002428  0.0000856  -2.837  0.00456 ** 
carrier.genderMale -0.5164417  0.1428549  -3.615  0.00030 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) total 
total       -0.934       
crrr.gndrMl -0.169 -0.068
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should not trust the results from a model that has not appropriately converged. Start from a simpler model including only the random intercepts for couples, and see if this converges and the variance is positive. Also, fit the model using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature, i.e., set `nAGQ` to 10 or 15.

Comment: If I use only couples I still get a singular fit.  Theoretically the outcome shouldn't be effected by the couple or the cycle but I feel it should be included in the model as some couples have many embryos while others only have 1.

Comment: It will be difficult to see what it's going on without trying on the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dimitris.  I think I just don't understand stats well enough to know what I'm doing.  I have tried this as you suggested but still get the singular fit error.
m5=glmer(segregation~total + carrier.gender 
         +(1|couple), data=data1, family=binomial,nAGQ = 10)

Comment: If I change nAGQ to equal 0 I no longer get the singular error.  I have attached a link to some raw data @Dimitris [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1si2ewnz5ZGicxe2s0p4oXolJKV4PU3G4/view?usp=sharing)